# How do I make "ctrl + shift + n" in VS Code open a new window connected to WSL?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I'm in VS Code I want to be able to press "ctrl + shift + n" and get a new window that's connected to WSL.

I have the WSL extension.

I'm aware I can add `--remote wsl+Ubuntu` to the Windows shortcut target, but that doesn't affect the shortcut in VS Code.

Rebinding "ctrl + shift + n" doesn't work with any of the following, with or without "terminalFocus",

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+n",
    "command": "wsl.openInNewWindow",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
  }

  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+n",
    "command": "remote-wsl.explorer.openDistroInCurrentWindow"
  }

  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+n",
    "command": "remote-wsl.explorer.connectInNewWindow"
  }
```

[image: Image showing the key bind doesn't work]